# Get Product Details based on Product Id in WCS

Tags: attributes, shopping-cart, product, websphere-commerce

I am new to WCS. new to Stackoverflow too...

Could someone please help me how to get Color and Size attributes based on product Id in Shopping Cart Page?

when clicking on the link in Shopping cart page, it will redirect to Quickview page. i dont want that. user should be able to select the size and color in shopping cart page itself...

Please let me know if you need anything else...

Answer (score 0):

All the logic you need are in OrderItemDetail.jso and ProductDescription_Data.jspf .

you need to make sure of :

- only itemBeans are added to shopping cart
- when you loop them , you need to get the parent product for that itemBean , and then go over all the SKUs and combine their defining attributes in lists to show them .
- also please note that sometime , itemBeans can be the only SKU of the product , in other word that product have one single SKU .. so there will be no options to select 
  and sometimes that itemBean can be categorized under category without parent product .. called category item bean .. this will have NO parent product and you need just to show that SKU options .

a snippet to retrieve CatEntry form Solr would be like:

```
<wcf:getData type="com.ibm.commerce.catalog.facade.datatypes.CatalogNavigationViewType" var="allCatEntryInOrder" expressionBuilder="getCatalogEntryViewParentInfoByIDNoEntitlementCheck">

    <wcf:param name="UniqueID" value="${orderItem0.catalogEntryIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>
    <wcf:contextData name="storeId" data="${WCParam.storeId}" />
    <wcf:contextData name="catalogId" data="${WCParam.catalogId}" />
</wcf:getData>
```

then to get the Parent CatentryId you need to call solr again same as above but with

```
<wcf:param name="UniqueID" value="${aCatEntry.parentCatalogEntryID}"/>
```

please read about `expressionBuilder` and SearchProfiles because there are many of them , each one have it is own usage depending of the data you intended to return from solr.

hope this is give you idea where to look and do your solution.

Thanks

Abed

Comment: you also need to write events in you drop down to call OrderItemUpdateCmd to update orderId with the new selections